# How to center a MapBox GL JS map at the point coordinates from a point edited with MapBox-GL-Draw plugin

Tags: javascript, mapbox, html, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using MapBox GL JS and the mapbox-gl-draw plugin in a simple MapBox map .... here you're the code ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- *** References for MapBox GL Draw ... -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl-draw.css' type='text/css'/>

    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<PUT_YOUR_KEY_HERE>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

// *** Add zoom and rotation controls to the map ...
//      osm_map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation({position: 'bottom-left'}));
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

// *** Add the draw control to the map ...
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        point: true,
        trash: true
    }
});
map.addControl(draw, 'top-left');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the user click / edit a point on the map I'd like to set the map center at the lat / lon coordinates of the edited point.

Suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Events for Mapbox GL Draw at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/API.md#events

You can use it like this:

```js
map.on('draw.create', function (e) {
  if (e.features.length && e.features[0].geometry.type == 'Point') {
    var center = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
    //map.setCenter(center);
    map.easeTo({center: center});
  }
})
```

https://jsbin.com/recuyufixu/edit?html,output